# Laravel 4 Controller Before and After function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a Base Controller that all other controllers will extend it.
I want to do some theme and validation and also loading widgets in its Before function.

I know that i could handle this with Routes filter but i don't want to place my code inside router i want to every controllers actions first execute "Before function" and then execute "After function" of this Base controller like Laravel 3.

```
class FrontController extends \BaseController {
    protected $layout = 'home.index';
    public function __construct() {
     }

    public function before() {
        // Do some theme and validation
    }


    public function __call($method, $parameters) {

        return Response::abort('404');
    }
```

Update : I'm looking for a way that for example I could change theme based on a page config or load sidebars widgets after main controller completed its function and ... Because of that I want to access to  $this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://four.laravel.com/docs/controllers#controller-filters), you can define before and after methods in your controllers in two ways.

With a filter name:

```
$this->beforeFilter('auth');
$this->afterFilter('something_else');
```

or with a closure:

```
$this->beforeFilter(function() {
    // code
});
```

These would go in your base controller's `__construct` method.

Here's a complete example:

```
class BaseController extends Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Always run csrf protection before the request when posting
        $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on' => 'post'));

        // Here's something that happens after the request
        $this->afterFilter(function() {
            // something
        });
    }

    /**
    * Setup the layout used by the controller.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    protected function setupLayout()
    {
        if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
        {
            $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Benjamin but the problem is that when we use closure we couldn't use $this because we are not in Object context.
For example this will throw an exception : 

 public function __construct() {
      $this->afterFilter(function() {
            var_dump($this->layout);
        });
    }

Comment: @MiladRey You can pass a parameter to a closure

Comment: I tried this:

public function __construct() {
      $this->beforeFilter(function($obj) use ($this) {
            var_dump($obj->layout);
        });
    }

but It throws 
"Compile Error: Cannot use $this as lexical variable"

Comment: You should be able to do something like $layout = $this->layout and then pass $layout instead of $this

Comment: Another approach in PHP 5.4+ is that you could actually bind the filter closure to a controller method, by binding $this to that closure. That allows for a nicer constructor :)

Comment: Too late to the party, but defining a new variable, and passing that new variable works as you intend: `$self = $this; .... function ($obj) use ($self) ...`